# Python Requests авторизация

Tags: python, авторизация, requests

Добрый день, есть тут загвоздка по поводу авторизации.
Есть сайт на ява и ajax авторизацией <s>htтps://tender.sk.kz</s>
При входе должен быть установлен сертификат, requests справился с этим, а вот
при вводе пароля уже стопор: логина нет, только пароль, при каждом входе всегда меняется ссылка.

Как отследить динамический параметр отправки формы?('_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON')

И как работать с xpath?

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off"
 size="0" name="passwordField" onchange="" 
class=".LoginText" title="Пароль" id="passwordField">
===
<button type="submit" onclick="submitForm('DefaultFormName',1,
{'_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON':'SubmitButton0OGtbcTW'});return false"
style="background-image:url(/OA_HTML/cabo/images/swan/btn-bg1.gif)"
class="x7g" title="Вход" id="SubmitButton">Вход</button>
==============================
 import requests
    cert =('cert','key')
    password = "qwerty123"
    auths ={'passwordField':password}
    URL = "htтps://tender.sk.kz/OA_HTML/AppsLogin"
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(URL, cert=cert, headers=headers, verify=False)
    auth_page = r.url
    r = s.post(auth_page, headers=headers, data=data)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Ответ параметр]

Comment: Логин, наверное тоже нужно передавать или сертификат сам по себе логин?

Comment: Логин не передаётся.
Т.е при авторизации через сертифиат он присваивает временную ссылку и там же тебе предлагает ввести пароль.